# Parsing the DOM using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Here's the HTML:

```
<p class="date range"> "March 2014 to Present"
  <span class="duration"> (1 year 9 months) </span>
  <span class="location"> California </span>
<p class="date range"> "2009 - 2013"
  <span class="location"> Country </span>
</p>
<p class="date range"> "2007 - 2008"
  <span class="location"> Country </span>
</p>
```

my code:

```
data = soup.find(id="profile-experience")
for li in data.find_all("p", class_="date-range"):
  print li.get_text()
```

What I'm getting

```
March 2014 – Present(1 year 9 months)California
2009 – 2013Country
2007 – 2008Country
```

I'd like to just get the date range so it would look something like this:

```
March 2014-Present
2009-2013
2007-2008
```

I'm not sure how to parse the data since there isn't a space between the second date and "Country".

Also, how do I get the date range without pulling any of it's children?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use BeautifulSoup to extract text before the first child tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10154289/use-beautifulsoup-to-extract-text-before-the-first-child-tag)

Comment: I wasn't sure how to use `.previousSibling`. It ended up just giving me the data the previous tag, not just some of the text inside the current tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea would be to get *the first text node* from every `p` element with classes `date` and `range`:

```
for date_range in soup.select("p.date.range"):
    print(date_range.find(text=True).strip())
```

Prints:

```
"March 2014 to Present"
"2009 - 2013"
"2007 - 2008"
```

Comment: Why does `print(li.find(text=True).strip())` work but `print li.get_text()` doesn't?

Comment: @MorganAllen that's because we've found a text node (`NavigableString` instance, in BeautifulSoup terms).

Comment: ahh, so you're saying .find(the first node where text=True)?

Comment: @MorganAllen yup, the `text=True` helps us find text nodes.